# Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary(...) fails after moving code to async/await

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using pocketsphinx in a Xamarin Android app (using MVVMCross) for speech recognition. It works great when I use it in the View, and it works great when I moved it from the View into a plugin so that I could use it in the ViewModel (using callback event handlers).

Now I am refactoring (again!) to use async/await, and the app fails to load the pocketsphinx library. My code is below. When I reach the call

```
Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("pocketsphinx_jni");
```

I get an exception:

```
Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library pocketsphinx_jni not found; tried [/vendor/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so, /system/lib/libpocket...
```

I've tried a combination of things using `Application.Context.ApplicationInfo.NativeLibraryDir` and `Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Load` but no joy.

Any ideas on why this would start to happen now? Presumably something to do with threading, but I am stumped as to how to solve the issue. All of this code worked fine before I started refactoring to use async/await.

The call in my ViewModel is:

```
var result = await _speechRecognitionService.ListenAsync(delay);
```

And here is my SpeechRecognitionService class:

```
public class SpeechRecognitionService : Java.Lang.Object, 
    ISpeechRecognitionService, IRecognitionListener
{
    private SpeechRecognizer _recognizer;
    private Java.IO.File _assetDir;
    private bool _isHandlingResponse;
    private bool _isInitialised;
    private static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private string _response;

    public event EventHandler HeardSpeechEventHandler;

    public bool IsInitialised()
    {
        return _isInitialised;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hopefully fire off the listen asynchronously
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="delay"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<string> ListenAsync(int delay)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => DoListen(delay));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialise if required then fire up the listener
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="delay"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string DoListen(int delay)
    {
        if (!IsInitialised())
        {
            Init();
        }
        Listen(delay);
        return "";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set up the config for the listener
    /// </summary>
    public void Init()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SpeechRecognitionIntentService ====== Init");

        try
        {
            // THIS CALL FAILS!
            Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("pocketsphinx_jni");
            _assetDir = Edu.Cmu.Pocketsphinx.Assets.SyncAssets(Application.Context);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to synchronize assets when attempting to load voice recognition software", e);
        }

        var config = Decoder.DefaultConfig();
        config.SetString("-dict", JoinPath(_assetDir, "models/lm/cmu07a.dic"));
        config.SetString("-hmm", JoinPath(_assetDir, "models/hmm/en-us-semi"));
        config.SetString("-rawlogdir", _assetDir.AbsolutePath);
        config.SetInt("-maxhmmpf", 10000);
        config.SetBoolean("-fwdflat", false);
        config.SetBoolean("-bestpath", false);
        config.SetFloat("-kws_threshold", 1e-5);
        //config.SetFloat("-samprate", 8000);
        //config.SetBoolean("-remove_noise", false);

        _recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config);
        _recognizer.AddListener(this);

        // Create keyword-activation search.
        //_recognizer.SetKws(KwsSearchName, Keyphrase);

        // Create grammar-based search for guide.
        var lw = config.GetInt("-lw");
        AddSearch("guide", "guide.gram", "<guide.command>", lw);

        // Create language model search.
        //var path = JoinPath(_assetDir, "models/lm/weather.dmp");
        //var lm = new NGramModel(config, _recognizer.Logmath, path);
        //_recognizer.SetLm("forecast", lm);

        _isInitialised = true;

        Console.WriteLine("InitVoiceRecognition done.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Listen for "delay" seconds. Use a timer. The timer and the speech recognition callbacks both use the _isHandlingResponse flag to decide
    /// who is handling the response. If the user speaks before the timer elapses then the speech recognizer callbacks set the flag and handle
    /// it by returning the spoken string to the HeardSpeechEventHandler. If the timer elapses first, then it sets the flag and sends an empty string
    /// back to the HeardSpeechEventHandler. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="delay"></param>
    public string Listen(int delay)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start listening for {0} seconds.", delay);
        //_recognizer.StopListening();

        try
        {
            _isHandlingResponse = false;
            _recognizer.SetSearch("guide");

            var timer = new Timer(_ =>
            {
                // If the speech recognizer is not handling the response already (i.e. the user hasn't spoken) then
                // set the flag and return an empty response
                if (!_isHandlingResponse)
                {
                    _isHandlingResponse = true;
                    _recognizer.StopListening();
                    //Debug.WriteLine("The timer elapsed for the delay of {0} seconds with NO RESPONSE ({0})", delay, CurrentObject.Label);
                    //if (HeardSpeechEventHandler != null)
                    //{
                    //  HeardSpeechEventHandler(this, new SpeechResult() {Result = string.Empty});
                    //}
                    Console.Write("Timer elapsed so setting response to '' and setting wait handle");
                    _response = string.Empty;
                    _waitHandle.Set();
                }
            }, null, delay * 1000, Timeout.Infinite);

            _recognizer.StartListening();
            Console.WriteLine("Started listening, now waiting for wait handle...");
            _waitHandle.WaitOne();
            return _response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred attempting to listen: {0}", ex.Message);
            return "";
        }
    }

    //public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p0"></param>
    public void OnPartialResult(Hypothesis p0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Partial result: " + p0.Hypstr);
        // If the timer is not handling the response already (i.e. timer hasn't timed out yet) then
        // set the flag and stop listening. This will kick off the OnResult function.
        if (!_isHandlingResponse)
        {
            _isHandlingResponse = true;
            _recognizer.StopListening();

            Console.WriteLine("Partial result: " + p0.Hypstr);
        }
    }

    //http://www.albahari.com/
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p0"></param>
    public void OnResult(Hypothesis p0)
    {
        //if (!_isHandlingResponse)
        //{
        //  _isHandlingResponse = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Full result, setting response to '{0}' and setting wait handle", p0.Hypstr);

        //if (HeardSpeechEventHandler != null)
        //{
        //  HeardSpeechEventHandler(this, new SpeechResult() {Result = p0.Hypstr});
        //}
        _response = p0.Hypstr;
        _waitHandle.Set();
        //}
    }

    public void OnVadStateChanged(bool p0)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        //Console.WriteLine("OnVadStateChanged: {0}", p0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    /// <param name="ruleName"></param>
    /// <param name="lw"></param>
    private void AddSearch(String name, String path, String ruleName, int lw)
    {
        //File grammarParent = new File(Path.Combine(_assetDir.AbsolutePath, "grammar"));
        var grammarParent = JoinPath(_assetDir, "grammar");

        var jsgf = new Jsgf(Path.Combine(grammarParent, path));
        var rule = jsgf.GetRule(ruleName);
        var fsg = jsgf.BuildFsg(rule, _recognizer.Logmath, lw);
        _recognizer.SetFsg(name, fsg);
        Console.WriteLine("AddSearch done.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent"></param>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static String JoinPath(Java.IO.File parent, String path)
    {
        return new Java.IO.File(parent, path).AbsolutePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to call this method in the UI Thread?

Comment: @hugo The call to ListenAsync comes from the UI thread, but presumably the init() function happens in a different thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by getting the UI thread of the current activity to load the Pocket Sphinx library, like so:

```
Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => 
                Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("pocketsphinx_jni"));
```

It feels a little wrong to do it like this (why should my plugin need to know anything about the current UI thread?) - but it works.

Comment: It's not easier with InvokeOnMainThread(() => Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("xxx"));  ?

Comment: @hugo I think that is an iOS feature, from the docs "The InvokeOnMainThread method is defined on NSObject so it can be called from within methods defined on any UIKit object (such as a View or View Controller)." http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_2_-_working_with_the_ui_thread/

Comment: Hi. It's useless because your project runs under Android but you can find the method InvokeOnMainThread under Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxMainThreadDispatchingObject.  The syntax is implemented for every platform

Comment: As much as hate to resurrect an 8 year old question, this issue is caused by a [design oversight](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/7616#issuecomment-1344497606) in the Xamarin Android runtime. It will be fixed in a future release but for now, the workaround is indeed to only call `LoadLibrary` from the main thread.